# javascript override new tab page chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to create an extension for Google Chrome overriding the "new tab" page, in which there is content in JavaScript. In the first tab, it runs correctly, but when new tabs are opened, the scripts don't work. What should I do for fixing it?

Comment: without any code, we can't help you. Why do you need to override the new tab button?

Answer (score 7):

You can make an extension for Google Chrome. Chrome extensions require a `manifest.json` file to be included, and you can set overridable pages to `bookmarks` `history` or `newtab`. Like such:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
```

For more info about making Chrome extensions, [read the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'content in JavaScript'.

You can check out the code for my chrome extension, New Tab Redirect: https://github.com/jimschubert/newtab-redirect

The way I have it set up is that there is a `redirect.html` page which is used as the override page.  On load, it checks for a user-specified url from the background/event page (background.js), then redirects to that url with a simple JavaScript redirect.

The `master` branch is v1.0 (background *page*) and the 2.0 branch uses an event page.

**edit**
To specifically answer *why* you might be having problems with your code, without seeing any actual code.. I assume you're doing the initialization of your script in a background page in very much the same way as in my extension and querying that data from the redirect page, where you're then getting/setting data in local storage.

If any of that data needs to change, you can't use local storage from your redirecting page.  Instead, you need to send the data back to the background page and store options there. Think of your background page as a *service* and your redirecting page as a very thin, very stateless client.